# Using setuptools to copy non .py files

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

My python project installs via `setup.py`. The project structure looks like:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── circle.yml
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── deps.txt
│   ├── guide_installation.rst
│   ├── guide_model.rst
│   ├── guide_transliteration.rst
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── module_trans.rst
├── indictrans
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── _decode
│   ├── _utils
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── iso_code_transformer.py
│   ├── libindic_
│   ├── mappings
│   ├── models
│   ├── polyglot_tokenizer
│   ├── script_transliterate.py
│   ├── test.py
│   ├── tests
│   ├── transliterator.py
│   ├── trunk
│   └── unicode_marks.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── test-requirements.txt
└── tox.ini
```

where the subfolder `indictrans/models` looks like

```
├── ben-eng
│   ├── classes.npy
│   ├── coef.npy
│   ├── intercept_final.npy
│   ├── intercept_init.npy
│   ├── intercept_trans.npy
│   └── sparse.vec
├── ben-guj
│   ├── classes.npy
│   ├── coef.npy
│   ├── intercept_final.npy
│   ├── intercept_init.npy
│   ├── intercept_trans.npy
│   └── sparse.vec
```

so I have `.npy` and `.vec` files to be included in the project.
In my `setup.py` I'm trying to explicitly include this folder `models` via the `include_package_data` directive like:

```
setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'models': ['*.npy','*.vec']},
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

and in the `setup.cfg` I have

```
[files]
packages = 
    indictrans
```

but running `python setup.py install` does not copy the models folder to the installation folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indictrans/`.

If I print the it is the output of the `find_packages` I get

```
['indictrans', 'indictrans.tests', 'indictrans.libindic_', 'indictrans._utils', 'indictrans._decode', 'indictrans.polyglot_tokenizer', 'indictrans.models', 'indictrans.trunk', 'indictrans.libindic_.utils', 'indictrans.libindic_.soundex', 'indictrans.libindic_.utils.tests', 'indictrans.libindic_.soundex.utils', 'indictrans.libindic_.soundex.tests', 'indictrans.libindic_.soundex.utils.tests', 'indictrans.polyglot_tokenizer.tests', 'indictrans.trunk.tests']
```

so I will assume that `indictrans/models` would be included, but it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add `include_package_data=True` to your `setup`-function (you already did that).
2. Create a file `MANIFEST.in` in the same directory as `setup.py`

`MANIFEST.in` can look as follows:

```
include indictrans/models/ben-eng/*
include indictrans/models/ben-guj/*
```

You don't need `setup.cfg` for doing this.

Source: [This great writeup of python packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html)

EDIT about `recursive-include`:
According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) this should also work:

```
recursive-include indictrans/models *.npy *.vec
```

Comment: Thanks. It would work recursively, so doing `include indictrans/models/*` or maybe `include indictrans/models/*/**`?

Comment: Thank you it works using recursive copy and `MANIFEST.in`.

Answer (score 3):

`include_package_data=True` requires [MANIFEST.in](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords).

To include data for the module `indictrans.models` you have to provide the full name:

```
package_data={'indictrans.models': ['*.npy','*.vec']},
```

Comment: Using `package_data` will need `include_package_data` + `MANIFEST.in`?

Comment: No, they'are two independen ways to [include data](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).